# При повторном запуске скрипта значения не добавляються в массив, а заменяют первое значение

Tags: массивы, php

**Добрый день!** Есть форма, в которой пользователь заполняет два поля ввода текста и эти два поля после нажатия на кнопку попадают в массив `PHP`. Вопрос в том, как сделать чтобы при повторной работе скрипта, значения продолжали добавляться в массив, а не заменяли первое значение и можно ли это вообще реализовать на `PHP`?

**P.S.** Пробовал через $_SESSION, не помогло.

```
$_SESSION['test'][$_POST[key]] = $_POST[invite];
print_r($_SESSION['test']);
```

Comment: `session_start();` не забыли в самом начале вставить?

Comment: sergiks, после добавления:
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at ...:1) in ... on line 1

Comment: @ka5itoshka, посмотрите на строку 1, там у вас вывод, которого быть не должно до `session_start();``

Comment: Первая строка, перед HTML-Доктайпом:
<?php session_start(); ?>

Comment: а файл сохранен не в UTF-8 with BOM?

Comment: Не поверите, как раз в нём. Уже вспомнил, сохранил в кодировке ANSI и всё гуд. Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт!

Comment: Поверю, но не обязательно уходить от UTF, просто сохраните в UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы всё время переписывали значение, потому оно и переписывалось. Попробуйте вот так:

```
$_SESSION['test'][$_POST[key]][] = $_POST[invite];
```

Comment: Не помогло. Всё равно при повторном запуске скрипта значение заменяет первое:
Array ( [test] => Array ( [0] => 123 ) )

Если запустить ещё раз:

Array ( [test2] => Array ( [0] => 123 ) )

Comment: Проблема в чём-то другом. У вас двухмерный массив, а мой код создает 3х-мерный. Плюс, почему ``test`` и ``test2``? У вас проблема где-то в ином месте.

Comment: test - значение которое передалось в качестве ключа первый раз, test2 - второй. Вопрос был в том как запустить два раза скрипт и сохранить ДВА раза ключ - значение в массиве.

Comment: исправьте сначала ``session_start();``, всё и решится